# Error while generating sweeper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everyone is like this is sweeper. But can anyone please tell me how to create sweeper file for a particular controller. I copy pasted the code but its not working.

Comment: what is the error u got?

Comment: my controller name is myfolder so error is `ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant MyfolderSweeper:`

Answer (score 0):

**[Sweepers](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Caching/Sweeping) are the terminators of the caching world and responsible for expiring caches when model objects change. They do this by being half-observers, half-filters and implementing callbacks for both roles. A Sweeper example:**

```
class ImageSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Image

  def after_save(record)
  def after_save(image)
    expire_cache(image)
  end
  
  def after_destroy(image)
    expire_cache(image)
  end
  
  def expire_cache(image)
    ##expire_fragment #'image'
      expire_cache(image)
  end
end
```

**The sweeper is assigned in the controllers that wish to have its job performed using the cache_sweeper class method:**

```
class ImageController < ApplicationController
  
  cache_sweeper :image_sweeper, :only => [ :edit, :destroy, :share ]
end
```

**In the example above, three actions are responsible for expiring those caches**

Above will only work if you have `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in `development.rb`

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I know this part can you please explain where should i put that sweeper file and with what name?

Comment: @ShilpiAgrawal name can be anything ..just need to include in controller ...thats it...but you need to cache something to make the sweeper work...hope you are caching too

Comment: Yeah i am caching it. For me its not working. Where to keep sweeper file?

Comment: keep it in app/sweepers and it will get autoloaded

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Sweeper file will be in app/sweepers/controllername(without s)_sweeper.rb